# Ng-repeat wont work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

JS:

```
function ctrlr($scope, $http) {
    $http.post(urlhere).success(function(data) {
        $scope.Items = data;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlr">
        <div ng-repeat="item in Items">
           {{ item.Name }}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Data returned from post request is a list of a class object (that contains Name property)

Checked, data is not empty.
It returns an xml formatted response.

Why won't my ng-repeat work? Tried using jquery ajax, which returned json but still no go

Comment: ``function(data)``, can you give us what is inside ``data`` more precisely?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running ng-repeat on a js object instead of array you should do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in Items">
  <span>{{key}}</span>
  <span>{{val}}</span>
```

Comment: Still the same, displays nothing. Though, it did display the divs with the text (explicit) "{{ val }}" for like half a second and then nothing.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the data you're getting ?

Comment: The web service is in an internal network, so no. It is really basic though, the web service returns List<Type> where Type is a simple class with some properties.

Comment: yes but you can create fiddle by copy pasting the data you're getting back in a js variable.

Comment: Again, it is an internal network - cant copy anything to jsfiddle since the pc isn't connected to the internet.

Comment: i can't really see where the problem is until i can have a look at data. maybe you can put down an example of data here?

Answer (score 0):

Well it may sound silly but the problem was that `$scope.Items` is being initialized in the success, an async method so it was undefined when it arrived to ng-repeat.

I solved it by switching to jquery ajax and adding `async: false`

Comment: That's not how angular is supposed to work. There was certainly another issue that you've bypassed. I suggest you to read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: Furthermore, making synchronous calls from your client will really lower the performances of your application.